# Nancy on Owin doesn't serve static content

Tags: owin, nancy

I'm running self hosted Nancy web application on Owin and have troubles with static content.

Let's say my application runs from this folder:

> c:/myfolder/

My Views are in here:

> c:/myfolder/Manager/Views/

so in my browser I can go to `http://localhost:85/Manager` and my page loads.

I simply can't make it to serve static content though, all my files are in /Content folder, I tried to place it both to /myfolder and /Manager folder with no luck.

Neither `http://localhost:85/Manager/Content/css/styles.css` nor `http://localhost:85/Content/css/styles.css` urls work

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by adding these lines of code to `Startup` :

```
using Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems; 
using Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles;

...

var options = new FileServerOptions()
{
    RequestPath = PathString.Empty,
    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("/Path/here")
};
app.UseFileServer(options);
```